# Copy text from <span> to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, copy, clipboard, copy-paste

I've been trying to copy the `innerContent` of a `<span>` to my clipboard without success:

#### HTML

```
<span id="pwd_spn" class="password-span"></span>
```

#### JavaScript

*Function Call*

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('copy').addEventListener('click', copy_password);
});
```

*Function*

```
function copy_password() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("pwd_spn").select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

I've also tried:

```
function copy_password() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("pwd_spn").textContent;
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

It seems like `.select()` doesn't work on a `<span>` element since I get the following error on both:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639681/how-to-copy-text-from-a-div-to-clipboard

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You could do this: create a temporary text area and append it to the page, then add the content of the `span` element to the text area, copy the value from the text area and remove the text area.

Because of some security restrictions you can only execute the `Copy` command if the user interacted with the page, so you have to add a button and copy the text after the user clicks on the button.

```js
document.getElementById("cp_btn").addEventListener("click", copy_password);

function copy_password() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("pwd_spn");
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = copyText.textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    textArea.remove();
}
```

```html
<span id="pwd_spn" class="password-span">Test</span>
<button id="cp_btn">Copy</button>
```

Comment: This would loose HTML markup, but not a big deal if they are just after text.

Comment: @epascarello You mean because of the text area being appended?

Comment: Thank you for your idea. It's run success

Comment: but how did you get this idea @rafaelgomesxyz sir/mam?

Comment: I found this did not work, until I changed ```document.execCommand("Copy")``` to ```document.execCommand("copy")```

Comment: Works in late 2021 as well, at least in Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48020189/2240670 there is a snippet of code for that gives you an example for a div, that also applies to a span, I did not copy it here to avoid duplication.

Basically, when you are copying to clipboard you need to create a selection of text, `<textarea>` and `<input>` elements make this easy because they have a `select()` method, but if you are trying to copy contents from any other type of element like a `<div>` or `<span>`, you'll need to:

1. Create/get a `Range` object(some browsers do not provide a constructor, or a decent way to do this). Calling `document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)`, I found works on most browsers except edge(ie11 works though).
2. Add the element you want to copy from to that range's selection.
3. Add that range to the window or document `Selection`.
4. Call `document.execCommand("copy")` to copy the selected text.

I also recommend checking the API of `Selection` and `Range`, that will give you a better grasp of this.

Answer (score 0):

**simple method** 
1)create a input
2)give style **z-index -1** and it will be hide

```js
    var code = $("#copy-to-clipboard-input");
    var btnCopy = $("#btn-copy");

    btnCopy.on("click", function () {
        code.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
    });
```

```html
                                                                                             
<input type="input" style="width:10px; position:absolute; z-index: -100 !important;" value="hello" id="copy-to-clipboard-input">
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-copy">Copy</button>
```