# copy text to clipboard by click on parent element

Tags: javascript, html

I Want copy inner span text to Clipboard by click on parent element of it, my Html code is like this:

```
<div> <span> text to copy </span> </div>
<div> <span> text to copy </span> </div>
<div> <span> text to copy </span> </div>
```

and my Java Script code it is:

```js
const mySpan = document.querySelectorAll('span');

mySpan.forEach(element => {
    var parSpan = element.parentElement;
    parSpan.addEventListener('click', () => {
        var elIn = element.innerHTML;
        document.execCommand('copy');
    });
});
```

i used of execCommand but its not copied to Clipboard , where is problem?

Comment: Why should `document.execCommand('copy')` copy the content of `elIn` into the clipboard? How would `document.execCommand('copy')` know to copy the content of `elIn`?

Comment: i dont know, how it can to know this? ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some information about copying text from span. You have to create temporary textArea to do so: [Copy text from <span> to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236100/copy-text-from-span-to-clipboard)

Comment: (.execCommand)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand] is obsolete, you should use [Clipboard_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Note: [document.execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) is absolute as mentioned by MDN documentation,
You can implement clipboard copy using [Clipboard API (write)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API), you can read more about the implementation [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi), also note that this implementation need user [permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API) to allow browser access to clipboard, this code snippet will not work here since its sandboxed but will work locally:

```js
const mySpan = document.querySelectorAll("span");

mySpan.forEach((element) => {
  var parSpan = element.parentElement;
  parSpan.addEventListener("click", () => {
    navigator.permissions
      .query({
        name: "clipboard-read",
      })
      .then((permissionStatus) => {
        // Will be 'granted', 'denied' or 'prompt':
        console.log(permissionStatus.state);
        if (permissionStatus.state === "granted") {
          navigator.clipboard
            .writeText(element.textContent.trim())
            .then(() => {
              console.log("Text copied to clipboard");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              // This can happen if the user denies clipboard permissions:
              console.error("Could not copy text: ", err);
            });
          console.log("text copied!!");
        } else {
          console.error("Could not copy text: ", err);
          throw "can't copy, need permission";
        }
        {
          {
            /* cpyText(); */
          }
        }
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<div> this is parent element!!1 <span> text to copy1 </span> </div>
<div> this is parent element!!2 <span> text to copy2 </span> </div>
<div> this is parent element!!3 <span> text to copy3 </span> </div>
```