# How to copy text from <a data-=""> to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html

As you can see from the snippet, the "Copy to Clipboard" function works when the text comes from `<input value="text">`, but I am failing to replicate the same function when the text comes from `<a data-text="text">`.

I'm assuming `copyText.select()` is limited to value from `input` and `textarea` only.

What would be the easiest way to make copy text from `<a>` work?

```js
function copyFromButton(id) {
  alert("Clicked but not copied:" + document.getElementById(id).dataset.text);
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById(id).dataset.text;
  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}

function copyFromInput(id) {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById(id);
  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" id="buttonCopy" data-text="text to be copied from button" onClick="copyFromButton(this.id)"> Cick to Copy </a>
<hr>
<input type="text" onclick="copyFromInput(this.id)" id="myInputRec" value="text to be copied from input" readonly="readonly" >
```

Comment: Put the output of `buttonCopy.dataSet.text` into the input, and then select/copy the new value?

Comment: Why do you pass only the element's id to the listener ? Just put `this` as argument, and you won't need to use `getElementById` in the listener's body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy text from a div to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639681/how-to-copy-text-from-a-div-to-clipboard)

Comment: @Seblor I used this function for another part of my site, which reuses the same function with multiple inputs fields.