# how to grab value inbetween span tags with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, clipboard

To copy a value to the clipboard, i use this function:

```
$(function() {
   $('.copy-to-clipboard input').click(function() {
      $(this).focus();
      $(this).select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
   $(".copied").text("Link copied to clipboard").show().fadeOut(1200);
   });
});


<div class='copied'></div>

<div class="copy-to-clipboard"> 
   <input type="text" value="Text to grab" /> 
</div>
```

how can i achieve the same with the value in betweeen `span` tags like below:

```
<div class="copy-to-clipboard"> 
   <span>Text to grab</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639681/how-to-copy-text-from-a-div-to-clipboard/51261023) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an input element with the value of the text in the span copy text and remove the input automatically

```js
$(function() {
   $('.copy-to-clipboard > span').click(function() {
     var a=$('.copy-to-clipboard > span').text();
     var t=a.split(" ").join('');
    $('.copy-to-clipboard > span').append('<input value='+t+'>')
    
    $('input').select();
  
      document.execCommand('copy');
       $('.copy-to-clipboard > span > input').remove()
   
   $(".copied").text("Link copied to clipboard").show().fadeOut(1200);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="copy-to-clipboard"> 
   <span>Text to grab</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

$('.copy-to-clipboard input').click(function()

change to

$('.copy-to-clipboard **span**').click(function()

should work

Comment: i also tried it but that does not work

Comment: <div class="copy-to-clipboard"> 
   <input type="text" value="Text to grab" /> 
</div>  <div class='copied'></div>    you should also swap like this, and double click full span for it to copy