# Copy text between p tags to clipboard in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create copy to Clipboard Component. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class CopyClipboard extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { copySuccess: 'Copy to Clipboard!' }
  }

  copyToClipboard = (e) => {

    this.textContent.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    e.target.focus();
    this.setState({ copySuccess: 'Copied to Clipboard!' });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="positioning">
        {
           //if i need
        }

          <p onClick={this.copyToClipboard} ref={(c) => (this.textContent = c)}>yotam@gmail.com</p>
        <div class="success">{this.state.copySuccess}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default CopyClipboard;
```

I get `Parsing error: Unexpected token` error. But if i use `input` tag then its work fine. Where i have done wrong?

Comment: @UweKeim what do you mean by this? what should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For p tag, you can't use `.select`.

You need to use `selectNode` and `addRange`

Try something like this for the selection function

```
copyToClipboard = async e => {
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(this.textContent);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  this.setState({ copied: true });
};
```

[Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-bird-9rxv3) for a working example too

Also [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36640126/2041906) to select text between non input tags.

Comment: but its not copy the text

Comment: I don't need any button. I need when i click on text then the text will be copy. And the text should have in `p` tag.

Comment: Its working. But i want to show when hover on text then it will show "Copy to Clipboard" after clicking it will show "Copied to Clipboard". You can see in question what i have done it.

Comment: thank you very much. I am accepting your answer. If i use condition like: `{copied==false ? <p class="success">Copy to Clipboard</p> : <p class="success">Copied to Clipboard</p>}` it working.

Comment: I tried this with the button, but it's putting in two returns. (also does this in your codesandbox example)