# Copy to clipbord on jquery not worked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my coding i was tried to copy table td text when onclick td using jquery...
i got the value of child  td is fine. but i cann't copy that word into clip board using .select() and execCommand("copy")..here is my jquery code

```
$('.copytd').on("click",function(e) {
  var copyText = $(this).closest('tr').find(".cpy").text();
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("copied Text:"+copyText);
 });
```

and my table td is

```
 <td align="center" ><span class = 'cpy'><?echo $row['ipno'];?></span> <span class="copytd text-primary"> Copy</span> </td>
```

then i have changed my text as copied before copy the text

Comment: can you show the html code.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra i was post my td code

Comment: is this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery/22581382

Comment: @Dilek i doesn't need any input element.. i need copy from td then i need to paste using ctrl+v

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy text from a div to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639681/how-to-copy-text-from-a-div-to-clipboard)

Comment: you heva to create temporary input and pass value to it and copy it.