# How can i copy in clipboard with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I copy the content of the element into the clipboard when I click on an element.

```
<h1 class="copy"> i want to copy this text on clipboard when I click on an element.</h1>
<p> i want to copy this text on clipboard<p>
```

Is it possible to copy without creating any element? Is there a solution similar to this?

```
$(function (){
$("h1").click(function (){
   $(this).select();
   document.execCommand("copy");
});
```

});

How can I do this with jquery or regular javascript. Or what are your other suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639681/how-to-copy-text-from-a-div-to-clipboard

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://www.30secondsofcode.org/blog/s/copy-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the navigator [clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API). It is supported by all modern browsers.

```js
document.querySelector(".copy").onclick = (e) => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.currentTarget.innerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<h1><button class="copy"> i want to copy this text on clipboard when I click on an element.</button></h1>
```

jquery:

```
$(".copy").on('click', function (){
  var text = $(this).text()
  console.log(text)
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(text).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();

});
```