# How do you avoid copy/paste content with a ':' coming out url encoded on an iPhone browser?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I have a web app that puts content on the browser clipboard:

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText("Name: Joe Schmo\nAddress:\t550 W. Someplace Ave\n\t\t\tAnytown\t\t\t55555\nPhone:  555-555-5555")
```

Recently my iPhone users have started complaining that when they paste this content it is "Full of % signs and numbers."

When they sent me a copy of the results I could see that it has been url encoded.
`Name%3A%20Joe%20Schmo%0AAddress%3A%09550%20W.%20Someplace%20Ave%0A%09%09%09Anytown%09%09%0955555%0APhone%3A%20%20555-555-5555`

I suspect that I am running into a bug or undesired feature in the latest iOS or safari update and I need a workaround.

After some experimenting I have determined that it only happens when the text I put on the clipboard has a ':' in it.

Here is a codepen which shows the issue:
https://codepen.io/jasonleenaylor/pen/MWLMYZq

Anyone have a workaround or solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the string as innerText of an invisible element or value of an invisible TextArea and then copying its content.

```html
<textarea id="copier" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

```js
const copyText = `Name: Joe Schmo\nAddress:\t550 W. Someplace Ave\n\t\t\tAnytown\t\t\t55555\nPhone:  555-555-5555`;
let copier=document.getElementById("copier");
copier.value=copyText;
copier.select();
navigator.clipboard.writeText(copier.value)
```

---

You can also try something like (from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48020189/14799428):

```html
    <html>
        <body>
            <div id="a" onclick="copyDivToClipboard()"> Click to copy </div>
            <script>
                function copyDivToClipboard() {
                    var range = document.createRange();
                    range.selectNode(document.getElementById("a"));
                    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); // clear current selection
                    window.getSelection().addRange(range); // to select text
                    document.execCommand("copy");
                    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();// to deselect
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

---

If even that doesn't work try to [override the copy event](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#override-copy) after you've called copy.

P.S.: Even though [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) is deprecated most modern browsers support both execCommand("copy") and execCommand("cut"), so I didn't edit the code in the 2nd section.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to change the behavior. Did you try those solutions on an iPhone?